# Unable to assign method reference to generic interface method

Tags: java

I am trying to assign a method reference to the following generic interface.

```
interface Interface1<R> {
  public R doIt();
}

interface Interface2<P, R> {
  public R doIt(P x);
} 

public class Test {
  public static Long foo(Long x) {
      return x;
  }

  public static Long bar() {
      Long x = 1L;
      return x;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface1<? extends Number> fun1 = Test::bar; //works
    Interface2<? extends Number, ? extends Number> fun2 = Test::foo; // does not work
  }
}
```

The second assignment gives me

> incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to Long

What am I missing here!

Comment: Note by way of comparison that in the standard library you always see `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`.

Comment: But then why Interface1<? extends Number, ? extends Number> f1 = (Long x) -> x; works?

Comment: Because in the second case it is defined to return `Number`, not `Long`.

Comment: Ah.. thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-. Doubt cleared. And learnt something new today

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this because then you can do `fun2.doIt((Number)0.5);`
The idea is that you need something like
`Interface2<? super Number, ? extends Number>`